# Image block module translate

Tags: 7, blocks, i18n-l10n

I have created block using image block module. I want to translate block content in other languages. I have used i18n module for translation. currently I only translate the title of the block. But I also want translate body content. So,please anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the [image block module](https://www.drupal.org/project/imageblock) is not yet fully compatible with i18n module and you will need to apply the patch in [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/imageblock/issues/1373794) which according to the posters is reviewed and ready to be committed.

**Alternatively** you can install [nodeblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeblock) and create a content type (i.e. *block*) and use it as a nodeblock and you will get all the benefits of *nodes* and *blocks*.  Therefore you can add image fields or any other fields that you need and after creating a node of that content type you will be able to add it in a region of your theme like a normal block. Nodeblock supports translatable content (Contrent translation with i18n and Entity Translation).

Comment: I used nodeblock module with i18n . This work perfect for me what I needed. Thanks for help